# Mysql query concate data into group concate

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

[image]

Here is my table. I have made  the following query and get the result:

### mysql - Query:

```
                 SELECT   

 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('', j0.rent_agree_id,'-',j0.rent_sche_id) ) AS agreement_ref_no
                FROM
                  rent_provision_history AS j0

                  GROUP BY provision_date
```

### Result:

[image]

But I want to see the result differently.

For example for the last result row i am getting now: 4-68,4-69,6-107,6-108,6-109

But I want to see it like that:
4(68,69)|5(107,108,109)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT provision_date,
       GROUP_CONCAT(rent_agree_id, '(', rsi, ')' SEPARATOR '|') agreement_ref_no
FROM (SELECT j0.rent_agree_id, GROUP_CONCAT(j0.rent_sche_id) as rsi
      FROM rent_provision_historyj0
      GROUP BY j0.provision_date, j0.rent_agree_id
     ) j0
GROUP BY j0.provision_date;
```